# Powershell Get-Content to msg.exe gibberish with Non-ascii characters

Tags: powershell, cmd, msg

I am trying to use the msg.exe to display the content of a txt file to remote computers.

The txt file (text.txt) contains non-ascii characters:

```
中文
英文
日文
```

When I try to use the following command, the pop-up window cannot display the characters properly.

```
Get-Content text.txt | msg <user> <server name>
```

I have studied the following codes, which the authors claimed that they work. However; I do not get them work. The content of the txt file cannot display in the pop-up window in whole. Each line will trigger one window to pop up.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/bf1a5583-7779-4009-a26a-321f70deca88/getcontent-to-msg-special-characters?forum=winserverpowershell

First one:

```
$content = Get-Content C:\Powershell\test.txt
Invoke-Command -ComputerName <Computer01>,<Computer02> {msg * $args[0]} -ArgumentList $content
```

Another one:

```
Get-Content test.txt |%{msg * $_}
```

Are there any methods that can overcome the problem of stdin of msg.exe?

Comment: `msg * (Get-Content text.txt -Raw)`

Comment: @PetSerAl It works properly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this, it seems to work for me :

```
Get-Content D:\temp\test.txt -Encoding UTF8 |%{msg * $_}
```

It gives :

[image]

I use [this](https://gist.github.com/JPBlanc/37a771268a6e76e306a3#file-test-txt) file.

To have the entire message :

```
Get-Content D:\temp\test.txt -Encoding UTF8 -Raw |%{msg * $_}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. It does not work for me. I am using Windows 7 Ultimate, Powershell 4.0.

Comment: @DanEng Same configuration with a french Windows 7 professional.

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't work for me. By the way, from your captured screen, it seems that the window only allows one line? Thank you.

Comment: @DanEng no that's just that the command line generate 4 messages (4 boxes).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would like to have just one window to hold the entire message.

Comment: @DanEng You can see it now.